# Entering an unknown number of words untill another word is entered

Tags: java, string, loops, integer, counting

How do I input an unknown quantity of names until the string "@@@" is typed in? And when that is complete, how would I count the number of names that have been input before the program ended.

Please correct this if possible:

```
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter in a name");
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    String end = "@@@";
    boolean found = name.indexOf(end) >= 0;
    while(found == false)

    {
    int newcount = count + 1;
    String newname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter in a name");
    }

    System.out.println("You have stopped the program because your name has ' " + end + " ' in it.");
```

Comment: You missed a big tag : java! please remember to use the right tags, specially in the case like these it has a great advantage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
int count = 0;
while(true) { 
    try {
        String newname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter in a name");
        if (newname.equals("@@@"))
            break;
        count++;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        //do something rational
    }
}
System.out.println(count);//change this as you wish
```

Comment: judging by the wording of the question, I am wondering whether `contains` maybe a better method?

Comment: @user2310289:Maybe. Depends on his/her wish. I understand what you say, but I think he uses exactly '@@@' as a sentinel not sth like '@@@abcfdsf'. In that case, yes `contains` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using a do-while loop something like this.

```
int count = 0;
String end = "@@@";   
String name = null;
do {
 name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter in a name");

 count++;
} while(name.indexOf(end)==-1);

System.out.println("You have stopped the program because your name has ' " + end + " ' in it.")
System.out.println("Total Names Entered : " + --count);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your count will be wrong.  it increments even if `@@@` is entered

Comment: Please see the last sop where i am printing it by using --count. Please do not downvote without reading full solution Thanks

Comment: Duh, sorry did not see.  Although if I did not see, then maybe not the best? Maybe comments?

Answer (score 0):

insert the following at the end of your while loop:

```
if (newname.equals(end)) found = true;
```